# Validating Azure AD Token signature fails JAVA

Tags: java, azure, active-directory, digital-signature, access-token

I am struggling to validate an Azure AD token signature.

When I look up the correct key description in the "jwks_uri" field under

https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration

I check the belonging key data .

I try to use the "n" - modulus and "e" fields to generate the public key for the signature validation I end up with an error:

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();        
byte[] modulusBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(n);
byte[] exponentBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(e);

BigInteger modulusInt = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
BigInteger exponentInt = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);

try {
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKeySpec publicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulusInt, exponentInt);
RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey)keyFactory.generatePublic(publicSpec);
Jwt<Header, String> c = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(pubKey).parsePlaintextJwt(token);

} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Console:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: Unable to verify RSA signature using configured PublicKey. Signature length not correct: got 256 but was expecting 246
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.RsaSignatureValidator.isValid(RsaSignatureValidator.java:50)
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.DefaultJwtSignatureValidator.isValid(DefaultJwtSignatureValidator.java:47)
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:351)
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481)
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parsePlaintextJwt(DefaultJwtParser.java:503)
at com.ge.hc.pfh.poc.ams.filter.JwtFilter.doFilter(JwtFilter.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at com.ge.hc.pfh.poc.ams.filter.ApiOriginFIlter.doFilter(ApiOriginFIlter.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at com.ge.hc.pfh.poc.ams.filter.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:34)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried another approach to use the "x5c" filed which is a base 64 encoded cert chain:

```
byte[] certChain = Base64.getDecoder().decode(x5c);
X509Certificate cert = X509CertUtils.parse(certChain);
PublicKey pubKeyNew = cert.getPublicKey();
Claims claims3 = Jwts.parser()
          .setSigningKey(pubKeyNew)
            .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
```

I end up with an other error:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: JWT signature does not match locally computed signature. JWT validity cannot be asserted and should not be trusted.
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:354)
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481)
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parsePlaintextJwt(DefaultJwtParser.java:503)
at com.ge.hc.pfh.poc.ams.filter.JwtFilter.doFilter(JwtFilter.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at com.ge.hc.pfh.poc.ams.filter.ApiOriginFIlter.doFilter(ApiOriginFIlter.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at com.ge.hc.pfh.poc.ams.filter.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:34)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to ADAL library listed in the libraries officially recommended by microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First example**

Modulus and Exponent (`n` and `e`) in  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys` are encoded in `base64url` and not in `base64`, so the code to decode them should be

```
byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(n);
BigInteger modulusInt = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
```

Do not use old `com.sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`

If the JWT is signed you should not use `JWTParser.plaintextJwt()`. According to [documentation](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/master/src/main/java/io/jsonwebtoken/JwtParser.java)

> plaintextJwt: a compact serialized unsigned plaintext JWT string

Use instead `parseClaimsJws` or `parsePlaintextJws`. The second method only if the payload is a string non-JSON

**Second example**

The second example is basically right. I assume `X509CertUtils.parse(certChain)` is similar to

```
 InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(certChain);
 CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
 X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(in);
```

Modulus and exponent of the certificate are the same that the decoded, so public key is equivalent

There are two similar certificates in the link, check both. You should be able to validate the signature. If not, then the token is not signed with those keys

Comment: You are right, the second approach is correct. The problem is that azure returned an id_token and an access token. The validation is fine with the id_token and fails with the access token. As the documentation says on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-tokens: 
"[...] access tokens issued by the v2.0 endpoint can be consumed only by Microsoft Services. Your apps shouldn't need to perform any validation [...]."
"Currently, the only token validation your apps should need to perform is validating ID tokens. "

Comment: @HDCase, is your comment here still valid? I'm having issues with validating access_tokens from ad, but I no longer see the documentation that you are referring to. Just wanting to confirm.