# Validating Azure AD Signature in Java

Tags: java, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am a reasonably experienced Java developer (4-5 years) but new to Azure AD and its capabilities, so I apologize in advance for a potentially basic question. I have struggled to find any Microsoft documentation or Stack Overflow questions covering this topic in Java (vast majority being in C#) and from my understanding, C# has more Azure AD libraries than Java, hence the solution in C# will not necessarily be the solution in Java.

I am trying to complete a authentication POC based on a scenario in-which there is an existing Azure AD system, full of users, that I want to leverage as an authentication point. My Java application will collect the users username and password (I understand this is deprecated and non-ideal, but for legacy reasons required) and makes a call using the Microsoft adal4j library to an Azure endpoint which I can get to successfully return a JWC access token (in addition to a refresh and ID token).

This is my existing code snippet that retrieves the JWC access token.

```
private static AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(String username, String password, String 
AUTHORITY, String CLIENT_ID) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationContext context = null;
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
                "https://graph.windows.net", CLIENT_ID, username, password,
                null);
        result = future.get();
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }

    if (result == null) {
        System.out.println("ex)");
    }
    return result;
}

public void azureAuthenticate(String authority, String clientID, String username, String password){
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    try {
        result = getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(username, password, authority, clientID);
        DecodedJWT accessToken = JWT.decode(result.getAccessToken());
        //Want to verify the validity of this access token
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My code is largely based on this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-headless-java)

After receiving the token, I need to be able to validate its authenticity (I understand the business logic side of confirming its claims, but I am confused as to how to verify the signature is legitimate).

Thank you in advance for any help, I am happy to provide any clarifications needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The access token from the Azure AD is a JSON Web Token(JWT) which is signed by Security Token Service in private key. A [JWT token](https://jwt.io/) is a non-encrypted digitally signed JSON payload which contains different attributes (claims) to identify the user. The signature is the last part of the JWT and needs to be used for verification of the payload. This signature was generated with the algorithm described in the header(RS256 if issued from AAD) to prevent unauthorised access.Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens#validating-tokens) for more details about JWT token .

To validate signature , firstly we should retrieve and cache the singing tokens (public key) :1)The first call is to the discovery endpoint. It's URL is formed as '/.well-known/openid-configuration' .2) Then you will find lots of metadata here including the issuer value and the `jwks_uri` endpoint address to get the keys to validate the token's signature .

Token signing is implemented according to [JSON Web Key spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517). Using Key ID and X.509 certificate thumbprint values from the token's header (kid and x5t parameters respectively) and then find the appropriate public key in the obtained collection of keys to verify the signature. I am not familiar with java ,but you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482513/validating-azure-ad-token-signature-fails-java) which includes code sample for how to validate the signature in Java .