# Invalid signature while validating Azure ad access token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am getting invalid signature while using jwt.io to validate my azure ad access token (will shift to scala code after the manual checking).

I am using curl to generate the access token:

```
curl -s -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/token -d grant_type=password -d username=$username -d password=$pass  -d resource=$resID -d client_id=$id -d client_secret=$key
```

While it is giving me the access token, the response doesnt contain the "Id_token". Not sure why.

I am wrapping the public key from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys with BEGIN and END  certificate. (as mentioned in https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/01/24/Verifying-Azure-Active-Directory-JWT-Tokens.aspx)

I am not sure what else is missing.

The decoded header is as follows:

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "9FXDpbfMFT2SvQuXh846YTwEIBw",
  "kid": "9FXDpbfMFT2SvQuXh846YTwEIBw"
}
```

Comment: Can you share the decoded of the access token?

Comment: I have added the header. what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning: You are invoking a flow which is unsupported, and will be removed in the near future.**

The Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow (`grant_type=password`) is not supported in Azure AD with confidential clients (i.e. web app/web API, where there exists a `client_secret`). If you are confident your scenario requires the Resource Owner flow (very few scenarios actually warrant the risks introduced by this flow), then you should be invoking it with a `client_id` registered for a native client app (a public client). Alternatively, you should be invoking an interactive sign-in (if you are signing in actual human users), or pursuing the Client Credentials Grant flow (if this is a daemon/unattended service).

You are not getting an ID Token because the flow you've invoked (the OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow), does not define any concept of an ID Token, or an `id_token` response. In other words: you haven't asked for one.

If you add `scope=openid` to your Authorization Request, you'll be hinting to Azure AD that you're more or less interested in knowing stuff about the person who signed in, and you'll get an unsigned OpenID Connect ID Token in the response.

To https://jwt.io to verify the claims:

1. Ensure this is a token intended for you. (i.e. don't expect to be able to decode and verify a token that was not intended for you (where "you" are the `resource` in the Authorization Request, and the `aud` in the token claims).
2. Ensure you've selected the correct signing algorithm (`RS256`).
3. Ensure you're checking against the key with which the token was signed (use the `kid` header value from the JWT as a hint).
4. Ensure the certificate ends in `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` (I've found jwt.io doesn't care too much about how it starts.
5. Double-check your copy-pasting, it's easy to accidentally pick up extra characters.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. The only reason I used the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant flow was as currently I just wanted to check the authentication of the jwt token. I am assuming that the users accessing my API will have the access token through interactive sign-in.

Comment: Can we even validate the access token? According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482513/validating-azure-ad-token-signature-fails-java#comment70351819_41519896 we cannot validate the access token.

Comment: I have another question regarding the flow to be taken for my scenario. I have an independent rest api and I just want to validate the user who wants to access my api. which flow should be used for that?