# MSAL Access Token VS ID Token for validating API

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, msal.js

I am currently using Laravel and VUE3 as well as the msal-browser packaged to authenticate with Azure.

I have this working fine on the front end but I also have api endpoints set up in the same Laravel application and I would like authenticate requests to the endpoints.

I've read a few articles and posts online and I had installed a JWT library to authenticate the token. I have this working but only when passing the idToken as this is in a JWT format.

From the microsoft documents I should be using the access token, but as this is not in JWT format like the idToken and I could not validate the signature against the azure endpoints like with the idToken - what is best practice?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The access token AzureAD generates is a JWT, docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#token-formats. What is the IdP that you are using to generate your access tokens?

Comment: I found that it was due to the addition of a 'nonce' parameter that if included made the signature invalid. Here is the solution and a link to the a stack overflow post that provided the answer:

"Essentially, if you are getting access tokens to access your own resource server and not the Graph API, your scopes parameter should be [CLIENT_ID]/.default (and if you are using the access token to access the Graph API, you don't need to validate the token yourself)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317152/invalid-signature-while-validating-azure-ad-access-token-but-id-token-works#:~:text=Header%20you%20will%20see%20a,or%20JwtSecurityToken%20won't%20success%20.